# Estimated Time Left and Total File Size not showing up in Download

Tags: time, download-manager, file-download

I am downloading [Orcad Capture Lite](http://www.ema-eda.com/products/orcad/demosoftware.aspx) software package from [this official link](ftp://orcad_sp2:cat&bat@ftp.cadence.com/16.5_OrCAD_Lite_Capture&PSpice_Products.zip).

I am using the Download Acceleration Plus software, even after over 350MB of the file has downloaded, I am still not able to see the Estimated Time Left or the Total size of the file:

[image]

This has never happed with anything else that I have ever downloaded.

What's wrong? Is it some kind of security measure? or some kind of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the HTTP/FTP server is not supplying a **Content-Length** response header when serving the file, so your browser/download accelerator is unable to display the file's size.