# Why do some downloading files not know their own size?

Tags: browser, download

Occasionally, when downloading a file in a web browser, the download progress doesn't "know" the total size of the file, or how far along in the download it is -- it just shows the speed at which it's downloading, with a total as "Unknown".

Why wouldn't the browser know the final size of some files? Where does it get this information in the first place?

Comment: Dynamically created files don't have a size, they come over as a stream till EOF is reached.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does browser know how much page has been loaded?](http://superuser.com/questions/333697/how-does-browser-know-how-much-page-has-been-loaded), [Estimated Time Left and Total File Size not showing up in Download](http://superuser.com/questions/505537/estimated-time-left-and-total-file-size-not-showing-up-in-download) ...

Answer (score 119, accepted):

To request documents from web servers, browsers use the HTTP protocol. You may know that name from your address bar (it may be hidden now, but when you click the address bar, copy the URL and paste it in some text editor, you'll see `http://` at the beginning). HTTP is a simple text-based protocol. It works like this:

First, your browser connects to the website's server and sends a URL of the document it wants to download (web pages are documents, too) and some details about the browser itself ([User-Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) etc). For example, to load the main page on the SuperUser site, `http://superuser.com/`, my browser sends a request that looks like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: superuser.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: [removed for security]
DNT: 1
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 09 Jul 2013 07:14:17 GMT
```

The first line specifies which document the server should return.
The other lines are called headers; they look like this:

```
Header name: Header value
```

These lines send additional information that helps the server decide what to do.

If all is well, the server will respond by sending the requested document.
The response starts off with a status message, followed by some headers (with details about the document) and finally, if all is well, the document's content. This is what the SuperUser server's reply for my request looks like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Tue, 09 Jul 2013 07:27:20 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Jul 2013 07:26:20 GMT
Vary: *
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Tue, 09 Jul 2013 07:26:19 GMT
Content-Length: 139672

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    [...snip...]
</html>
```

After the last line, SuperUser's server closes the connection.

The first line (`HTTP/1.1 200 OK`) contains the [response code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_response_codes), in this case it's `200 OK`. It means that the server has decided it can return a document, as requested, and promises that the contents that follow will be such a document. If this is not the case the code will be something else, and it will provide some indication of the reason the server is not just returning a document as the response: for instance, if it cannot find the requested document, it is supposed to return `404 Not Found`, and if you are not allowed to access the content in question it is supposed to return `403 Forbidden`.

After this first status line, the response headers follow; they provide more information about the content being returned, such as its `Content-type`.

Next is an empty line. It signals the fact that no more response headers will follow. Everything past that line is the content of the document it requested. So in the above example, `<!DOCTYPE html>` is the first line of the SuperUser home page (a HTML document). If I was requesting a document to download, it would probably be some gibberish characters, because most document formats are unreadable without prior processing.

Back to headers. The most interesting one for us is the last one, `Content-Length`. It informs the browser how many bytes of data it should expect after the empty line, so basically it's the document size expressed in bytes. This header isn't mandatory and may be omitted by the server. Sometimes the document size can't be predicted (for example when the document is generated on the fly), sometimes lazy programmers don't include it (quite common on driver download sites), sometimes websites are created by newbies who don't know of such a header.

Anyway, whatever the reason is, the header can be missing. In that case the browser doesn't know how much data the server is going to send, and thus displays the document size as *unknown*, waiting for the server to close the connection. And that's the reason for unknown document sizes.

Comment: also will be omitted when being gzipped on the fly

Comment: A very, very minor note: Browsers support protocols other than HTTP. But other protocols are rare these days, and essentially the same concepts apply to other protocols even though the details are different.

Comment: @Thomas That is my experience these days. It’s been several years since I remember seeing an ftp URL in my browser. A few years ago I was using ftp—directly rather than with a browser—at work (almost entirely uploads), but those tasks are handled by scp now. The only thing I use ftp for today is uploading content to a minimalist web host. Of course, YMMV. ^_^

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer that makes me love this site. How do I grant it a bounty?

Comment: @ruda.almeida: You have to wait until the question is at least two days old, then the "start a bounty" button will become visible just below the question

Comment: @JeffWolski I believe all GNU downloads are done via FTP (in-browser).

Comment: Someone marked this as a duplicate (I disagree), so it seems I can't set a bounty to this answer =/

Comment: @ruda.almeida of you disagree with that, you can post about it on meta.superuser.com, it will be discussed and maybe someone will reopen the question.

Answer (score 55):

The HTTP `Content-Length` header is optional in some cases, and as such it may not be transmitted with the file; the end of the file will be signaled when the socket is closed.

Comment: To be precise, HTTP 1.0 defined the content length by closing the socket after each document. This is still supported in HTTP 1.1 for compatibility. But HTTP 1.1 allows to reuse connections for multiple documents if either the `Content-Length` header field is used or the document is transferred with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. The latter allows to dynamically generate content and send it piecewise as it gets generated and is able to signal the end of the document.

Answer (score 4):

When the content (e.g. a `.pdf` document or an Excel sheet) is created on the fly the size cannot be known before. In this cases the server cannot send you the size of the download before and the brower cannot display the total size.

Comment: Not true: when generating things on the fly they are either stored in a temp directory (which you can see the size of) or you can just count the length of the content that you are about to send to the user.

Comment: @alfo going to have to disagree... if I'm streaming video, or even if I'm streaming any sort of data that's not a fixed size, if the point is to get the data to the user as quickly as possible, I won't know the size at the point where I start the transmittal

Comment: We're not streaming PDFs... this question was about downloads.

Comment: @Alfo You can create data like `.pdf` files on the fly. As long as the data is not competely written you don't know the size but you can send the ata already to the browser. I've done this already in Java and sent an Excel file to the browser which as generated on the fly. From the browsers side it looked like a download but from the servers side it is a streaming. So it is possible to *stream* `.pdf` files even if you cnnot imagine this. From the browser it looks like a download without known length.

Comment: @Alfo Think about a live broadcast, you don't **need** to know the length to watch it, and in fact you don't know the length, since you presumably don't know (nor need to know) when the broadcast ends. That's the point. Some things just don't have a length until they have actually ended.

Comment: @UwePlonus nope. There is a difference. Video streaming: the video might not have been fully created by the time the user starts downloading it. This is a stream. What you are talking about is on-the-fly creation of files. The file must have finished being created before it is sent to the user. That is how HTTP works. It is easy to find the total size of an on-the-fly document before it is sent to the browser. You can do it in most programming languages. Here's an example in PHP: http://pastebin.com/acjteP7i

Comment: @Alfo - it only needs to be finished being created before the last packet is sent to the client.

Comment: True. But the original question is not about video streaming. It's not about viewing a video, or streaming audio, it's about downloading a file over HTTP, so all the arguments about video streaming are not relevant.

Comment: @Alfo I have never taked about *video* steaming but about *streaming* in general, which can also be streaming a `.pdf` file or an Excel sheet!

Comment: @Alfo - You have a valid point, dynamic files could be entirely created first in memory and then sent via HTTP and its easy to calculate content length.  However, if the server is sending many large dynamically created files that will be broken up into many packets, it makes sense for the server to just start sending the chunks as they are calculated (versus to having to create every large file in memory and then send it).  HTTP 1.1 specifically designed the [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) for this purpose.