# Why Chrome sometimes can't calculate the size of the downloaded file?

Tags: google-chrome

Have you ever expirienced when Chrome (or maybe another browser) sometimes can't calculate the size of the file you're downloading?

Do you know why this happens?

Comment: How does any browser know the size of a remote resource? It's just a guess, but it's somehow optionally hinted...I think the answer is in that somewhere. Did you test in other browsers?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/617327/why-do-some-downloading-files-not-know-their-own-size

Answer (score 1):

That's because the site you're downloading from hasn't transmitted that information to the browser.