# Why do downloads give bad files?

Tags: download

Why, when downloading, do network errors cause the download to finish and create an incomplete file?

Shouldn't the program downloading be able to recognize that the file is of `X` big, and it has only downloaded `Y` so far?

I'm assuming that it is a download that knows the size of the file.

Comment: Think about if someone sent you a 100 page document page by page. You get a load of pages and then a few don't turn up. Then a few more (not in the same order) arrive. If the first page tells you how many pages to expect then you know, but what can you possibly do to change how and when the pages arrive? You will still have an incomplete document...

Comment: @BigChris Sure, but I'd rather have a .crdownload file (in chrome's case) that indicates a partial download, than a bad completed file.

Comment: It depends on the quality of your down-load manager. Some of them are not very well written (to be polite). Plus, as @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 says, it is not always possible to determine the source file size. That is why many sites publish MD5 check-sums, though there does not seem at present a protocol to allow down-load managers to use this information.

Comment: @AFH "there does not seem at present a protocol to allow down-load managers to use this information" I'd assume that's because you'd need the whole file to use the checksum.  So you'd need to download the whole thing to check it anyway. ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - Precisely!

Answer (score 3):

Many transfer mechanisms have no idea what the size of the file they are downloading is.  Check out this related SU question: [Why do some downloading files not know their own size?](https://superuser.com/questions/617327/why-do-some-downloading-files-not-know-their-own-size)

Also, the transfer mechanisms have no idea what data is *supposed* to be in the file; so it has no idea if that `1` it just read in the download was actually a `1` at the source or if it's a `1` due to corruption during the transfer.

If the download stream encounters too many retries, a time-out elapsing, or other recognizable *transfer* errors, then the transfer is stopped.  Since download mechanisms save that download stream as it arrives, it writes the file until the incoming stream stops, regardless of why it stops.  Whether that incomplete file is kept or not after it's known to have a transfer failure, is up to the client/mechanism used.

Comment: I'm not asking about downloads that don't know the size.  I'm not asking why bad data creeps into downloads, but why that bad data (or no data) finishes the download prematurely.

Comment: You asked: "Shouldn't the program downloading be able to recognize that the file is of X big, and it has only downloaded Y so far?" So I stated that they (often) have no idea what the expected size of the file is, to explain why that can't be used to detect a problem.

Comment: I realized that when you posted, and made an edit :P

Comment: Why is bad data downloaded; because a single packet is corrupted by noise

Comment: Well… data corruption… If a single packet is corrupted in IP, it will be discarded. If it's corrupted in TCP, it will be retransmitted. That's why they have checksums. So where does the corruption really come from, then?